# Stable high performance BT client?

Tags: bittorrent

I need a BT client that is capable of downloading several dozen files at once, at 100mbit. I use uTorrent, but I found that its not able to keep up with the load. Memory usage goes up to 2GB and it freezes constantly when I try to download a lot of torrents at once.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Just a bad RAID array it seems. No problem on other drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**Halite**](http://www.binarynotions.com/halite-bittorrent-client), it's a great µTorrent alternative, very lightweight.

[image]

Comment: does Halite support [uTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol) the micro transport protocol? I can't find such text in it's options yet.

Answer (score 3):

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) is supposed to take very few resources.

Comment: I've tried quite a few bt clients in the past, and transmission is the best: great performance, easy to use, uses no resources, great UI,... It has no drawbacks as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I use Utorrent on a server with a 1GB port (limited to 200Meg connection), I have around 300 torrents at once minimum and it only takes up around 200MB or less, I find it the best client I have ever used.

I would join the [Utorrent IRC support room](http://www.utorrent.com/irc/) as they will help you to configure your client

Server: irc.p2p-network.net Channel: #utorrent (English only)

Personally, I find that manually setting the disk cache (read and write) helps me a lot to keep ram down - make sure you have the dynamic options off as on a high bandwidth server, it can really get eaten up quick.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Deluge, at least latest builds, that is - 1.x. I successfully used it on a 10 Mb/s connection before switching to Transmission